# How to make kotlin flow wait till end before Terminal operator is executed

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

```
/**
* Does some work and return true to denote success
* false to denote failure
*/
suspend fun doWork(): Boolean {

    val processStatus = processWork()

    return processStatus.filter { status ->
                status == ProcessStatus.SUCCESS 
                || status == ProcessStatus.FAILURE
            }.map { filteredStatus ->
                filteredStatus == ProcessStatus.SUCCESS
            }.single()
}


/**
* Cretaes a channel in which different status will be offered
*/
suspend fun processWork(): Flow<ProcessStatus> {

    val channel = BroadcastChannel(Channel.BUFFERED)
    doThework(channel)
    return channel.asFlow()
}


/**
* Does some work in background thread
*/
fun doThework(channel: BroadcastChannel) {

    SomeSope.launch {

        //Cretae a coroutine 
        channel.offer(ProcessStatus.Status1)
        channel.offer(ProcessStatus.Status2)
        channel.offer(ProcessStatus.Status3)
        channel.offer(ProcessStatus.Status4)

        channel.offer(rocessStatus.SUCCESS)
        channel.close()
    }
}
```

Above is a simplified version of my code.

What I want to do is, make `doWork()` wait till all the values are emmited and finally return a boolean based on last `ProcessStatus.SUCCESS` or `ProcessStatus.FAILURE`.

Right now, what is happening with the above code is, as soon as the `processWork()` returns the flow. `doWork()` calls all the operators including the `single()` and since, the work is still in progress ProcessStatus.FAILURE or ProcessStatus.SUCCESS is still not emmited, making it give an exception.

How can I make the `doWork()` return statement wait and return only when the flow is Complete?

---

Edit 1:

Reason, I have to go with the channel is because, this is part of an Android code & the `channel.offer()` is not actually a new co-routine like in example above, but is being called from a Android `BroadcastReceiver`.

Since flow is cold, I didn't want user leaving the Activity to stop the task from being completed and notified.

Comment: Any reason you want to use a channel? Can't you just use flowOn() and emit()s and let the coroutines-lib handle the channel stuff under the hood?
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-on.html

Comment: @MathiasHenze I replied to your question, via a edit block in my question.

Comment: What's the exception you get? I would expect this to work...

Comment: `NoSuchElementException("Expected at least one element")`

Comment: I don't fully understand the issue, but it seems, that there is at least a complication with operator-chains on hot flows: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1758. So trying @Andrei Tanana's suggestion to first convert the flow to a list seems like a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use [toList](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/to-list.html) method to collect all values before processing them:

```kotlin
suspend fun doWork(): Boolean {

    val processStatus = processWork().toList()

    return processStatus.filter { status ->
                status == ProcessStatus.SUCCESS 
                || status == ProcessStatus.FAILURE
            }.map { filteredStatus ->
                filteredStatus == ProcessStatus.SUCCESS
            }.single()
}
```